# Modifying the GL Batch generated when a Bills and Adjustments document is released

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

The goal is taking the Journal Transaction generated from the AP Bill page and adding 2 additional rows in GLTran.

**1st Attempt**

First, I extended the Release action from the Journal Transactions graph to include the 2 new lines:

```
        public class JournalEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<JournalEntry>
{
    public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
    [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        baseMethod(adapter);

        //new code
        GLTran tranRow = new GLTran();
        tranRow = this.Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert(tranRow);

        tranRow.AccountID = 2713;
        tranRow.SubID = 467;
        tranRow.CuryDebitAmt = 100;
        this.Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(tranRow);


        tranRow = new GLTran();
        tranRow = this.Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert(tranRow);

        tranRow.AccountID = 1514;
        tranRow.SubID = 467;
        tranRow.CuryCreditAmt = 100;
        this.Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(tranRow);

        this.Base.Actions.PressSave();


        return adapter.Get();
    }
```

**Result**: Creating and releasing the batch, entered the 2 new lines correctly.

After this, I thought that releasing the AP Bill would also trigger this extended logic from the GL Page. However, that didn't occur - The release of the Bill doesn't seem to re-use the *Release* logic defined in the GL page.

**2nd Attempt**

Then, I went back to the GL page and included the logic in the RowPersisted event, so that the 2 new lines would get created right after saving the document:

```
    public class JournalEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<JournalEntry>
    {
        protected virtual void Batch_RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Batch batchRow = (Batch)e.Row;

        if (batchRow != null
                && e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Insert
                && e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed)
        {
            ////new code
            GLTran tranRow = new GLTran();
            tranRow = this.Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert(tranRow);

            tranRow.AccountID = 2713;
            tranRow.SubID = 467;
            tranRow.CuryDebitAmt = 102;
            this.Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(tranRow);


            tranRow = new GLTran();
            tranRow = this.Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert(tranRow);

            tranRow.AccountID = 1514;
            tranRow.SubID = 467;
            tranRow.CuryCreditAmt = 102;
            this.Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(tranRow);

        }
    }
```

**Result**: Creating and saving the Batch correctly entered the 2 new lines.

After this, I thought that releasing the AP Bill would trigger this extended event, given that a Journal Entry graph should get created and used from the Bill page, but in this case, also releasing the AP Bill, did not add the 2 new lines in the generated Batch.

**3rd Attempt**

Then I thought I could extend the Bill's Release action and take control of the generated Journal Entry with the Search<> method. However, in this case, the extended logic seems to be executed within a transaction as the Document.Current.BatchNbr was still NULL:

[image: Current BatchNbr Null]

**4th Attempt**

Finally, I tried to extend the Persist() method of APReleaseProcess similarly to how it's done in the guide T300, however none of the methods are listed (version 17.207.0029):

[image]

Any other ideas as to how to enter these GL Lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully, it didn't take you forever to go through these 4 attempts... I've got to say though, the number of efforts and details in your question is quite impressive and definitely very appreciated!

A 2-step customization will be required to insert 2 additional GL Transactions in the Batch generated for an AP Bill:

1. to insert additional GL Transactions, you need to override **Persist** method within the **JournalEntry** BLC extension and invoke the logic to insert additional GLTrans only if the custom **ModifyBatchFromAP** boolean flag value equals ***True***:

   ```
   using PX.Data;
   using System;

   namespace PX.Objects.GL
   {
       public class JournalEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<JournalEntry>
       {
           private bool modifyBatchFromAP = false;

           public bool ModifyBatchFromAP
           {
               get
               {
                   return modifyBatchFromAP;
               }
               set
               {
                   modifyBatchFromAP = value;
               }
           }

           [PXOverride]
           public void Persist(Action del)
           {
               if (ModifyBatchFromAP)
               {
                   var glTran = Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert();
                   Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.accountID>(glTran, "20000");
                   glTran = Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(glTran);
                   Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.subID>(glTran, "000000");
                   glTran.CuryDebitAmt = 100;
                   glTran.TranDesc = "Additional Debit Transaction for AP Doc";
                   Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(glTran);

                   glTran = Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert();
                   Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.accountID>(glTran, "20200");
                   glTran = Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(glTran);
                   Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.subID>(glTran, "000000");
                   glTran.CuryCreditAmt = 100;
                   glTran.TranDesc = "Additional Credit Transaction for AP Doc";
                   Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(glTran);
               }

               del();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. after that in the overridden **Release** action within the **APInvoiceEntry_Extension**, you will subscribe to the **InstanceCreated** event for the **JournalEntry** BLC type to set **ModifyBatchFromAP** flag value to ***True*** allowing your logic from step 1 to execute for the Batch generated  only for an AP document:

   ```
   using PX.Data;
   using PX.Objects.GL;
   using System.Collections;

   namespace PX.Objects.AP
   {
       public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
       {
           public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);

           [PXOverride]
           public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
           {
               PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<JournalEntry>((JournalEntry graph) =>
               {
                   graph.GetExtension<JournalEntry_Extension>().ModifyBatchFromAP = true;
               });

               return baseMethod(adapter);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

P.S. it is not currently possible to use the Select Method to Override dialog with the **APReleaseProcess** class due to PXHiddenAttribute applied to it. Let me forward this to our Engineering Team to bring their attention on that matter.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response Ruslan! I will give it a try and will let you know the results.

Comment: That did it. Thanks Ruslan!

Comment: You're very welcome, @BillBlake! Glad this got resolved. May I please ask you to accept my answer?